# How do i redirect output from multiple programs/scripts to open in VIM as screen splits?

Tags: vim

What i want is a command to run from shell which supports:-

```
myprog1 'someinputfile1' |vim -
```

and

```
myprog2 'someinputfile2' |vim -
```

outputs opened in vim in split screen.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287164/how-to-redirect-stdout-output-to-a-new-vim-tab?rq=1
told me to use `vsp|myprog <someinputfile>` to split an already opened vim window.

Comment: I don't understand why this was migrated. It is a Vim question, and the accepted answer is a Vim answer. I thought Vim questions on StackOverflow were fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are on linux, try this:

```
vim -o <(myprog1 'someinputfile1') <(myprog2 'someinputfile2')
```

Change `-o` to `-O` to split vertically.

Comment: The program also takes an input file. Does it work still?

Comment: You can have `<(myprog arg1 arg2)`, or `<(myprog1 arg1 | myprog2 arg2)`

Answer (score 0):

Well the second one is easy, because it's just a sequence of commands:

```
ls | vim -
:vertical split
:enew
:read !ls
```

If you want diffsplit

```
ls | vim -
:diffthis
:vertical split
:enew
:read !ls
:diffthis
```

You could create a keyboard mapping for this, something like

```
:map <F12> :diffthis\|vertical split\|enew\|diffthis<CR>:read !
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Vim's `-c` argument to read the first output, open a new tab, and then read the second output. For example:

```
vim -c ':read !ls dir1' -c ':tabnew | read !ls dir2'
```